# Android Facebook content provider authority change programmatically

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-4.0

```
<provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider{app id here}"
android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
android:exported="true"/>
```

Can i change Facebook appId programmatically in Android app?

Comment: what appId? what do you mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to change it depending on your build type, you can use a string resource to replace the actual value of your Facebook Id.

```
<provider
android:authorities="@string/FB_APP_ID"
android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
android:exported="true"/>
```

Then on your build.gradle define the value of FB_APP_ID per built type.

```
buildTypes{
   debug{
        resValue "string", "FB_APP_ID",
        "com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider{appid1}"
    }
   release{
        resValue "string", "FB_APP_ID",
        "com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider{appid2}"
    }
}
```